# JSON to CSS table for Web

Tags: javascript, api, css, json, table

I need a pure JS API that turns JSON objects into a web table. I need the output to be in `<div id="primaryKey" class="css-class">` so that I can format the info and looks.

Comment: Can you code at all?

Comment: I googled for `json object to html table` and there are quite of code examples. It depends on how comfortable you are with putting them into your HTML. In the worst case, you could try, and, if it does not work, ask for help on https://stackoverflow.com/ (if you do, please leave a link here to the S.O question)